# Apache Ignite : Lazy References

Tags: java, data-modeling, ignite

Don't know how to properly formulate the title, but here is the problem.
Let's say I have a class `Person` and a class `Organization` and their association type is Many to One. In Java code `Person` object has a reference to `Organization` object and `Organization` has a `Collection` of `Person` objects. Both `Person` and `Organization` objects are `Serializable`. In addition to that I have programmed `Person` in such a way that it is affinity collocated with `Organization`.
If I put an instance of `Person` object into the cache (grid node) I would like to serialize only identifier of associated `Organization`, but not the whole object that is being referenced.
Is there any solution out of the box (some kind of proxy) that will skip serialization of associated object and will lazy load the associated object by identifier on a deserialized instance of `Person`?
I have already seen a custom solution for Oracle Coherence grid that is based on decorators, but the implementation is extremely complex.

Answer (score 1):

How about storing an ID of an organization instead of the whole `Organization` object? This is the proper way to collocate people with their organizations.

If you need to store an actual `Organization` object inside of a `Person` instance, you may make a `transient` field and update it lazily, when you access it. Something like this:

```java
class Person {
    @AffinityKeyMapped
    private int orgId;

    private transient Organization org;

    // Other fields, constructors, getter, setters.
}

// ...

// Accessor method in DAO logic.
Organization getOrganization(Person person, IgniteCache<Integer, Organization> orgCache) {
    Organization org = person.getOrganization();
    if (org == null) {
        org = orgCache.get(person.getOrganizationId());
        person.setOrganization(org);
    }

    return org;
}
```

This way org field won't be serialized, when `Person` is put into Ignite cache. Only `orgId` will be. And `Organization` will be requested from cache only once for a `Person` object. Subsequent calls to `getOrganization()` will use a saved value.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I was hoping to get other opinions/options and just forgot to thank you. The code you've shown implements the same concept that I've mentioned in my question, but delegates logic to DAO layer instead of introducing a proxy object. Unfortunately, not an option for me. I am trying to integrate with legacy code which uses cross references for calculations, a lot of cross references (and cycle references). Code that performs calculations is out of my control. So I can only extend existing classes. Hence proxy is the only option.